# Parent method that chooses child class (C#)

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm trying to avoid duplicate blocks of code--each dealing with different children of a parent. Here is an example of what I would like to avoid:

```
if (FormNumber == 0)
    {  
    Child1 obj = new Child1()  
    statements;
    }
else
    {  
    Child2 obj = new Child2()  
    statements;
    }
```

I would like to pass FormNumber to the parent class and use a parent function to determine which child class is used. I'm imagining a parent function like:

```
public Parent GetChild(int F)  
    {  
        if (FormNumber == 0)
            return new Child1();
        else
            return new Child2();
    }
```

and then in the main function

```
Parent obj = new Parent();  
Child? newobj = obj.GetChild(FormNumber);  
statements;
```

The problem is I need to figure out how to fill in the ? with the right Child class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up an inheratance hierarchy for `Child`.  If you set up a common interface for Child1 and Child2 then you can do the following:

```
Parent obj = new Parent();  
IChild newobj = obj.GetChild(FormNumber); 
// newobj may be a Child1 or Vhild2 object.
```

The hiearrchy may look like:

```
public interface IChild {
    public methods();
}

public class Child1 : IChild {}

public class Child2 : IChild {}
```

Your method could then look like:

```
public IChild GetChild(int F)  
{  
    if (FormNumber == 0)
        return new Child1();
    else
        return new Child2();
}
```

Comment: instead of creating an interface for a child to implement, why not just create an abstract method in the parent for the child to implement?

Comment: The children have a different number of parameters, so I don't think an interface will work here. I need an abstract class, I think. I've been looking at the abstract factory method but it seems rather complicated for a simple choice function.

Comment: @this, I'm not sure you are using inheritance correctly then.  I'm not sure what you mean by your above comment.

Comment: The children need to inherit some values from the parent, and depending on which child it is determines how the other values are set. If I use an interface it looks like I'll have duplicate blocks of code in the child class implementations and I'll have to explicitly set properties. I'm a newbie, so maybe I'm missing something here. Is there a way to pass values from the parent and use the interface choice function so that the properties are set in the child class?

Comment: @this, Ok.  I think you may want to us an `abstract` class for the parent class of your two child classes.  Have a look here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)/[strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern. Get them implement a similar interface and have it:

```
IChild newobj = obj.GetChild(FormNumber);
```